# Insert an array in a 4D array (Numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm extracting some features from some data generated with an accelerometer and I have the following arrays:

- X_mfccs_processed (list with 40 values)
- Y_mfccs_processed (list with 40 values)
- Z_mfccs_processed (list with 40 values)
- X_mean (1 value)
- Y_mean (1 value)
- Z_mean (1 value)

At the moment i'm able to create a 3D array [shape=`(1,40,3)`] and insert into it my mfcss arrays

```
self.extracted_features = np.ndarray(shape=(1, len(self.X_mfccs_processed), 3))
    self.extracted_features[:,:,0] = self.X_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,1] = self.Y_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,2] = self.Z_mfccs_processed
```

My question is: How can i create a 4D array [shape=`(1,40,1,3)`] where to store also my mean values?

Comment: Why are axis 0 and 2 the ones with dim 1? Also how do you want to store these mean values?

Answer (score 0):

To make the array, instead of assigning values to a preallocated array a better way is:

```
self.extracted_features = np.array([X_mfccs_processed,Y_mfccs_processed,Z_mfccs_processed]).T[None,...]
```

or equivalently:

```
self.extracted_features = np.array([X_mfccs_processed,Y_mfccs_processed,Z_mfccs_processed]).T.reshape(1,-1,3)
```

However, you cannot add another dimension with shape 1 and insert mean values in it. A dimension value is the number of elements along that dimension. An easy way to think about it is that a matrix of shape (1,N) is a 1xN matrix and it does not mean you can insert the mean in first dimension an a list of size N in the second dimension. You need to come up with another idea to store your means. I would suggest a separate array like this with shape `(1,3,1)`:

```
self.extracted_features_mean = np.array([X_mean,Y_mean,Z_mean]).T[None,...]
```

And use similar indexing to access the mean. An alternative would be using dictionaries. Depending on your application, you can pick one that is easier and/or faster.

Answer (score -1):

Usually `np.reshape(self.extracted_features, (1,40,1,3))` works well.

The shape would have to be different to store the mean values as well. There isn't enough space.

(1,40,1,6) or (1,40,2,3)

seem reasonable shapes.

for  (1,40,1,6)

```
self.extracted_features = np.ndarray(shape=(1, len(self.X_mfccs_processed), 1, 6))
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,0] = self.X_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,1] = self.Y_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,2] = self.Z_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,3] = self.X_mean
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,4] = self.Y_mean
    self.extracted_features[:,:,:,5] = self.Z_mean
```

for  (1,40,2,3)

```
self.extracted_features = np.ndarray(shape=(1, len(self.X_mfccs_processed), 2, 3))
    self.extracted_features[:,:,0,0] = self.X_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,0,1] = self.Y_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,0,2] = self.Z_mfccs_processed
    self.extracted_features[:,:,1,0] = self.X_mean
    self.extracted_features[:,:,1,1] = self.Y_mean
    self.extracted_features[:,:,1,2] = self.Z_mean
```

I should mention this casts the mean values meaning that it duplicates them (40 times). This would be bad for storage but if you doing some type of machine learning or numerics this might be a good tradeoff. Alternatively you could do a (1,41,1,3) shape.